# Smoothie Charts real-time high speed data

Tags: javascript, c++

I've got a high-speed data output from a C++ script, an int is produced every 800 microseconds(~1.6kHz), I've played around with this running with websocketd to stream it live to a smoothie chart on a web server on the same machine. I've found the best way to make the chart as smooth as possible is to output an array of 100 datapoints to the websocket. Inside my smoothie javascript, it splits the array and then adds the data with arbitrarily spread X values between the last array and this array.

```
'
conn.onmessage = function(evt) {
    $("#log").text("Connected");
    var arrZ = evt.data.split(',');
    newTime = new Date().getTime();
    var timeInterval = (newTime - oldTime)*0.01
    for (i=0;i<100;i++){
        timeSeries.append(oldTime, arrZ[i]);
        oldTime += timeInterval;
        }
    oldTime = new Date().getTime();};

'
```

The data plot is not fantastic but works. Is there any other(faster) way - architecture wise - to get this data on to smoothiecharts?
SmoothieCharts Charting high speed data

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that underneath, you're using TCP/IP packets. And with just a few bits of data on every update, these packets aren't immediately full. Your OS has the reasonable expectation that waiting a bit will improve bandwidth, as it can send the same amount of raw data with fewer packet headers.

However, this backfires for you. You care about latency, not data. The easiest solution is to stuff dummy data in your packets. Each value, once formatted and padded should be ~1500 bytes.